# Determining if Series involving Complex Numbers Converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

To start off, I'm very new to the complex plane and complex numbers.

I'm trying to determine if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2 + i}$ is convergent or divergent.

However, I'm not exactly sure how to express the value of the function. Could I just treat the denominator of the expression as the complex number's modulus and ignore the rotation in the plane? If I do that, I could determine that the series is convergent via a direct comparison test.

Geometrically speaking, it doesn't seem like a rotation would affect the convergence of a series. However, I don't know if I can consider the modulus of the complex number to be equivalent to its "value", and this is the cause of my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{1}{n^2+i}\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4+1}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4}} = \frac{1}{n^2};$$
thus, by the comparison test and $p$-test (with $p=2$) the series converges absolutely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to verify, the magnitude part of the complex number's polar form is its "value", and the rotation is something completely separate, correct?

Comment: Hi, $n^2$ is real and $i$ is imaginary, so $|n^2+i| = \sqrt{(n^2)^2+1^2} = \sqrt{n^4+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, you can always decompose it to the real and imaginary part:

$$\frac{1}{n^2 + i} = \frac{n^2-i}{n^4+ 1} = \frac{n^2}{n^4+1}-i\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Both the real and imaginary parts converge:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{n^4+1} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{n^4} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}< +\infty$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-i}{n^2} = -i\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2} = -\frac{i\pi^2}{6}$$

So in particular, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+i} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{n^4+1} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-i}{n^2}$$ also converges as a sum of two convergent series.